# Why WCHAR related code processing is needed

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t, wchar

I came across an application code and see that for the "Windows" specific code they have converted the command line arguments to do some additional WCHAR related processing (between #ifdef _WIN32).

What would be the reason for adding WCHAR processing related code for Windows in below snippet? I am trying to understand the rationale behind invoking the WCHAR related functions. In the end, the coder is trying to call  `myFunc` which could have directly been called using normal argC and argV. Why would someone feel to need to add additional processing of wchar?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

#ifdef _WIN32

    int argc_w;
    LPWSTR* argv_w = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc_w);
    std::vector<char*> argv_vector;
    int result;
    if (ConvertToUtf8(argc_w, argv_w, argv_vector)) {
        result = myFunc(argc_w, argv_vector.data());
    } else {
        result = myFunc(argc, argv);
    }

    // code to free vector
    return result;
#else
    int (*ptrMyFunc)(int, char**, const char*);

    void *dllHandle = dlopen(myDLL.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    *(void **) (&ptrMyFunc) = dlsym(dllHandle, "myFunc");
    return (*ptrMyFunc)(argc, argv);
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several reason, some are also wrong.

The `myFunc` function (I'll not comment the bad choice of the name) seems to require UTF-8 arguments. Now on MacOS and Linux you can expect it, but not on Windows. I think this is an error: one should not UTF-8, instead the program should check out the command line encoding.

But Windows adopted early Unicode, before UTF-8 became a thing (and possibly before Unicode discovered that it cannot fulfill initial goal: all characters in 16bit). So Windows uses internally UCS-2 or UTF-16, and externally there is ANSI, etc. but not really a standard (it depends on Language of Windows). The Windows function `CommandLineToArgvW` parse the command line into Unicode string, and it is the way to get command line, if you have non-ASCII characters (really, one should use `wmain`.  I'm not an expert in Windows API, but the above code smell. It seems some copy paste to solve few existing problems (e.g. command lines with non-ASCII chars, only modern MacOS/Linux) without understanding the problem and getting a clean solution.

Comment: Giacomo Catenazzi - I lost you in these lines. But Windows adopted early Unicode, before UTF-8 became a thing (and possibly before Unicode discovered that it cannot fulfill initial goal: all characters in 16bit). So Windows uses internally UCS-2 or UTF-16, and externally there is ANSI, etc. but not really a standard (it depends on Language of Windows).

Comment: `Windows uses internally UCS-2 or UTF-16, and externally there is ANSI, etc` Not sure what you *really* meant by this, but it is plain wrong as written. From Microsoft's [Unicode - Win32 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode): "*The system uses Unicode exclusively for character and string manipulation*". The same page also covers UTF-8, and the legacy 8-bit codepages that are still supported for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Microsoft was an early adopter of Unicode. Windows used UCS-2 for its Unicode handling until Windows 2000, then it switched to UTF-16 and has been using that ever since. Just about all Win32 ANSI-based APIs convert to Unicode internally before processing, and then convert results back to ANSI on output. It is best to avoid that conversion when possible, using Unicode-based APIs directly.

Comment: @dxiv: MS uses Unicode internally. See filesystems or resources (if you read them as binary data). But RemyLebeau wrote it is a much better way.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Not sure what you mean by "*internally*". The entire Win32 public API [is Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes), and has been since NT 3.5 last millennium. From the linked page: "*New Windows applications should use Unicode to avoid the inconsistencies of varied code pages and for ease of localization*". In this context "*new*" means 1994 and later.

Comment: @dxiv: yes "relatively new" (because UTF-8 was not yet a thing). The code in the question is a *portable* code (not really, but anyway), so it requires zero-terminated-char-strings. The WIN32 part seems to me just an hack to get ANSI (or other) char from terminal. Or it is how I interpreted the code: how to work around `main()` to get wchar, but to continue as normal C program. The `#ifdef _WIN32` tell me that we are not expecting to use Win32 API everywhere in the code. Maybe I was too zealous to introduce the unwanted historical context.